# How to clear transparent pixels in Phaser 3?

Tags: pixel, sprite-sheet

[image]

I tried to remove them using TexturePacker with option: "Clear transparent pixels" but that removed part of the sprite. And this is what happened:

[image]

After that, I restored the deleted part in Aseprite. But the transparent pixels appeared again. Also tried to delete everything around sprites with Wand tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How avoiding the texture bleeding issues on WebGL.

Tile Extruder is a node based CLI app that automatically fixes tileset images for WebGL, so they no longer have edge bleeding where the tiles join at the sides. It's easy to build into your workflow and includes sample code showing how to use the extruded tiles in Phaser 3.

```
tile-extruder --tileWidth 32 --tileHeight 32 --input ./tile_jungle_ground_brown.png --output ./tile_jungle_ground_brown-extruded.png
```

Note: you'll have to adjust your margin & spacing because of the extrusion. If you had no margin & spacing, then the new margin is 1px and the spacing is 2px.